# Highcharts: chart inside Tooltip: "image retention" in Firefox

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am trying to render charts inside HC Tooltips and facing a problem of "image retention" in Firefox and IE10. Only Chrome works fine. The problem is that some elements of tooltip charts (e.g. markers and legend borders) **stay on the main chart after tooltip is closed**. The demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/D3x89/

I am using this code to render charts in the tooltip:

```
    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function() {
            setTimeout( function() {
                $("#hc-tooltip").highcharts({
                    series: [{
                        data: [12, 23]
                    }]
                });
            }, 1510)               
            return '<div id="hc-tooltip"></div>';
        }
    },
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Thanks!

Edit. The code suggested by Pawel Fus makes it better, but still sometimes leaves the markers after closing the tooltip: the screenshot from FF 31:

[image: tooltip retention example]

Comment: Which version of FF / OS you have? In my (31.0 on macosx) works properly.

Comment: The problem shows on both FF 31 and IE9. Can you see the maker dots left on the main chart after closing the tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do two things:

- change delay before displaying chart
- destroy chart after tooltip hides

Example for both: http://jsfiddle.net/D3x89/2/

And code for destroying chart in tooltip:

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'hide', function (p) {
        p.call(this);
        var tooltip = $("#hc-tooltip").highcharts();
        if (tooltip) {
            tooltip.destroy();
        }
    });
})(Highcharts)
```

Comment: Thank you, Pawel, but it doesn't work all the time. Try hovering over the main chart and you will see - sometimes it hides the tooltip perfectly, sometimes leaves markers on the chart. See the image added to my post.